# What, in intuitive terms, is a local isomorphism of presheaves?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

The nlab [says](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+isomorphism) a system of local isomorphisms is a collection of weak equivalences (satisfying the [2-out-of-3 property](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-out-of-three)) which is stable under pulling back along maps from representable functors.

It turns out these creatures are exactly the ones inverted by sheafification, which justifies the name. However, I would like to understand the intuition behind the definition above, for instance, why the hell do representables pop up, and what does locality have to do with it? Will local isos satisfy [2-out-of-6](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-out-of-six+property) as well?

Also, what are some explicit geometric examples of local isomorphisms?

Comment: Local isomorphisms do not especially have any geometric meaning. After all, that is why they become isomorphisms after sheafification. Also, it immediately follows from that characterisation that they have 2-out-of-6, are closed under retracts etc.

Comment: I'd keep reading the article. As it says, representables come up because you're interested first of all in presheaves which are locally isomorphic to a representable, that is, which become representable after sheafifying. 

When your site has enough points, a local isomorphism is simply an isomorphism on stalks.

Comment: @KevinCarlson that a local iso is an iso on stalks is what I'd hoped. Unfortunately, I've only studied sheaves on spaces so far, and the word `stalk` does not appear in that article. So for spaces, are local isos simply isos on stalks, or is this "enough points" issue more subtle than that?

Comment: Spaces definitely have enough points, intuitively because they're defined by starting with a set of points, in contrast to most more general sites. You can check for yourself that local isomorphisms of presheaves on a space are simply stalkwise isomorphisms, using the fact that the sheafification functor preserves stalks, which is more or less readily apparent from the construction if you know one.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin Carlson said, on a site with enough points, such as topological spaces, the local isomorphisms of presheaves are precisely those which induce isomorphisms on stalks. In fact, you might not even need to check all of the stalks, only the stalks on a conservative family of points. They have a nice discussion of this in the Stacks Project page [here.](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00YJ)